# Search Kit with a Form to search for all contributions greater than X Contribution ID

Tags: searchkit, formbuilder

I just came across Search Kit as an answer to my Drupal Views that completely crashed after doing an update to Civi and Views. Cudos to those building Search Kit & Form Builder. From the little bit that I have messed with it, it seems super powerful.

I have built a search and added a table and form. I would like to have the form with a single input of a contribution ID # which will then query for all contributions greater than that ID. Right now it just seems to pull in that Contribution ID only. How can I create it for "greater than"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally the filter options on the form are more limited than those configurable within a search.  However, for your 'greater than' case you can achieve that as follows:

In your form, drag 'Contribution ID' on to the display to create a filter.

Then go to the cog icon to configure settings for your filter and tick the 'Search by Range' checkbox:

[image]

That gives you boxes for both the lower and upper end of the range. To search 'greater than' just enter a value in the first box and leave the second one empty.

Either sell the upper bound box as an extra feature (!), or use some css to hide it.

Comment: That is what I did but for some reason it would just show me one contribution. This time I deleted to old form and started over and created it with the "search by range" right from the start and it worked perfectly.